# How do I change the GPU graph that Windows Task Manager shows on the left side?

Tags: windows-10, task-manager

Windows 10 Task Manager shows the **3D** engine graph for my GPUs on the left side panel. How do I make it show a different GPU engine, like the **Compute_0** engine, as expressed in the image below?

[image]

Comment: It's not possible - we are not Microsoft.

Comment: "Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once."

I do have a specific problem. I included an image for detail. I didn't ask multiple distinct questions.

Comment: It means you were asking for too much.

Comment: Okay. What am I asking besides how to switch the graph? Is it that I asked, `Is this even possible?` That is part of the question. Is it that I said I want to change it to the **Compute_0** graph? That is adding detail to the question ("for instance" means "for example").

Comment: It's possible - for Microsoft.

Comment: The word `this` in `Is this even possible?` refers to the question, and the question asks how do **I** change it.

Comment: "Too Broad" is also somewhat of a catch-all in this case. The answer is that you cannot change this: it is hard-coded by Microsoft and so outside our, or pretty much anyone not-Microsoft, to do.

Comment: The question CAN be reopened, and the answer given that it is not possible. That IS an answer, and it is THE answer for this question.

Comment: Apparently I was supposed to know the answer to my own question. This is ridiculous.

Comment: @Alan, yeah, that cuts way down on our work.  :-)  music2myear is right, though.  This is a legitimate question that only an expert would know is hard coded.  There's nothing wrong with a question to which the answer is "you can't do that".  Even then, there might be a workaround, like third party software.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is that you cannot do this in the built-in Task Manager. The layout of the Task Manager is hard-coded and not customizable.

Your options are to find an alternative dashboard application which shows this content and either has a layout you prefer or allows you to choose a layout, or learn of some third-party product of which we are not currently aware which could redraw the Task Manager.